# How to make uploaded PDF text searchable in Apache Sling

Tags: aem, apache-tika, sling, jackrabbit-oak

I am exploring Apache Sling 11 to build a web application which is more content driven. I have a page where files(pdf/txt/doc) can be uploaded to path `/content/company/uploads` as `nt-file`. In search module I am using JCR query to do search for particular text and I wanted the text inside PDF/TXT files to be searchable, right now the search is able to pickup texts in txt file but not pdf files. The pdf file that I used for testing is just full of text.

I have configured tika in oak:index/lucene and did run a re-index but no change in query result.

**Apache Sling version** - 11
**Backend** - Mongo DB(oak-mongo)

**Query that is used**

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/company/uploads') AND lower([*]) LIKE 'test word'
```

**Tika configuration screenshot below**
[image: Tika configuration screenshot below]

I am just starting to learn sling, any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `like` I used `CONTAINS(*, '%test word%')` in query. But now the problem is the text inside txt files are not picked up.